# This code only working with alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, alert

I have a textarea that when you press tab, it inserts three spaces. Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">                                </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            textarea {
                tab-size: 3;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 9) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).val += "\t";
                        alert("Tab pressed");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code inserts the space all right, but when I take out the alert,it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything. `val()` is a function.

Comment: @SLaks It does do something. It adds '/t' to the function code making it a string. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6tQw/1/). Just messing... ;)

Comment: @Derija93: Yes, but it does that on an object which is immediately thrown away, so it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SLaks You're right. But my comment wasn't meant to be taken seriously. I was hoping that "Just messing" was enough indication to make that clear, but... now it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val()` is a method, not a property, so try:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.val($this.val() + "\t");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqsuM/)

Comment: @Ptr13 That doesn't proof anything. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hBUz9/1/). A textarea by default accepts tabs which is why you're thinking your approach functions properly.

Comment: @Ptr13 When you do an alert it is actually using the tab key press which is not by default handled in a input element to provide a space in tab, it does not make use of your code to append the `\t` which you intend to do. Remove it and see.